# Notification in Chat app using Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am creating demo for private chat using Firebase sdk. I am using [this](https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios) github demo. From this I am able to do chat but how can I get notification when my app is closed and someone send me message on it.

I am not able to find any solution after doing lots of RnD in Firebase, so please help me if anybody knows it solution.

Comment: You will need to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for that. This will require that you run some code on a server that you provide. For full information see the [Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and [questions asked about Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your help. I will try Firebase Cloud Messaging